# Problema al importar .csv con formato fecha(dd/mm/aa) y como decimal la coma

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Importada de un banco español, dispongo del fichero .csv, accesible en  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12D-Vdh5WmPiMcquMUg-3FYtKKtv8X3l1/view?usp=share_link)
En este fichero, las fechas tienen el formato "dd/mm/aa" y como decimal utiliza la 'coma'
Quiero importar estos datos en un DataFrame en el que las fechas tengan el formato "YY/mm/dd" y las cotizaciones utilicen el"punto" como decimal. Para ello hago.

```
import pandas as pd

# Dirección para obtener los ficheros 
os.chdir(path = "/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Py_Proyecto_2022/Gestion-Conservadora-de-Activos_Financieros/Datos/Ficheros_R4_csv")
df_temp = pd.read_csv("Acatis.csv" ,index_col = "Date", 
                      decimal  ="," , usecols = ["Date", "Close"], parse_dates=True, 
                      na_values = ["nan"], sep='\t')
df_temp.info()
```

Importa bien los datos en un DataFrame pero, por cada fila del fichero, imprime

```
/home/enri/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/base_parser.py:1070: UserWarning: Parsing '15/12/2008' in DD/MM/YYYY format. Provide format or specify infer_datetime_format=True for consistent parsing.
  return tools.to_datetime(
```

Es decir, si tengo 100 columnas, imprime 100 veces esta advertencia.

Cómo puedo resolver este problema?

Comment: Dos cosas: Primero, no puedo replicar el error usando un csv hardcodeado. Segundo, tu link no funciona, dice que necesito acceso. De cualquier modo, las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas. Considera que si el link se cae, la pregunta se volverá inutil para futuros lectores, e incluso para los que quieran dar sus propias respuestas a futuro. Lo que quiere decir, que te recomiendo poner una muestra del csv para que podamos hacer pruebas y ayudarte mas facilmente.

Comment: Si creo un diccionario con fechas y valores  con el formato comentado y lo convierto a DataFrame, el script funciona correctamente. La única manera de poder reproducir el problea es accediendo al fichero .csv

Comment: @efueyo, abre tu `csv` copia algunas filas y pégalas tal cual en la pregunta en una sección de texto para que conserve el formato del archivo. De esa forma nosotros podemos copiar y pegar y crear un archivo de prueba.

Comment: Al intentar pegarl lo copiado en el portapapeles, en la pregunta, me lo pega como imágen, y eso no erviría. Cómo puedo hacer para pegarlo como tú sugieres?.

Comment: He comprobado que el problema se resuelve añadiendo "mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")" y a continuacion de "parse_dates",  ",date_parser= mydateparser". Pero me advierte de que "...The pandas.datetime class is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version""".

Comment: Sabrias explicarme cómo funcionan estas sentencias añadidas?.

Comment: Probaste hacerle caso al consejo que te da la advertencia? Podes leer la documentación de pandas para saber que hace infer_datetime_format. Sobre el formato, pareciera que no hay indicios en la documentación de pandas que indique sobre como especificar un formato.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la siguente solución:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
# Dirección para obtener los ficheros 
#os.chdir("E:\Py_Proyecto_2020\Ficheros_R4_csv/")
os.chdir(path = "/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto/Ficheros_R4_Modificados_google/")
mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
df_temp = pd.read_csv("DedaloPP.csv" ,index_col = "Date", 
                      decimal  ="," , usecols = ["Date", "Close"], parse_dates=["Date"],date_parser= mydateparser,
                      na_values = ["nan"] )

# Cambir el formato de la fecha. (Change the date format.)
df_temp.index = pd.to_datetime(df_temp.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%d' )
df_temp
```

Aunque tiene el pequeño problema de que me devuelve esta advertencia.

```
/tmp/ipykernel_9666/4183925584.py:6: FutureWarning: The pandas.datetime class is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Import from datetime module instead.
  mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Comment: Es un tapabaches bueno por ahora. Pero esa advertencia te está indicando que lo que usas (pandas.datetime) será eliminado en el futuro. Si lo dejas así y algun día actualizas pandas, vas a tener que buscar otra solución. Yo usaría lo propuesto por la advertencia.

Comment: Eso es lo que no entiendo. Me dice "....Import from datetime module instead.". ¿Qué tengo que hacer?.

Comment: He hecho: import datetime
from datetime import datetime" y sigue dándo la misma advertencia.

Comment: He sustituido "pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")" por "pd.to_datetime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")" y me devuelve "AssertionError: " sin ningún otro texto.

Comment: A lo que se refiere esa advertencia, es que uses el objeto datetime directamente para hacer la transformación, NO a solamente importar el modulo. Tu lambda debería de quedar así `lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y")`, luego de haber hecho `from datetime import datetime` claro.